# How to retrieve data from a jsp page to my store using Sencha touch 2?

Tags: jsp, sencha-touch-2

I want to display the data retrieved from the JSP page in my List. I don't know how to do this .Here is my JSP page. Please correct the JSP page also.

```
**category_List.jsp**



  %@page import="java.sql.*, java.util.*" %>
<% 
response.setContentType("application/json");

String result = "{\"root\"[{\"category_name\": \"Model number\"}]}";
response.getWriter().print(result);
response.getWriter().flush();
%>
```

and my sencha code

```
Ext.define('Sample.view.Blog',{
           extend:'Ext.navigation.View',
           xtype:'bloglist',
           config:{
               title:'Blog',
               iconCls:'star',
               scrollable:true,
               styleHtmlContent: true,
               items:{
                   xtype: 'list',
                   itemTpl: '{category_name}',
                   store:{
                       autoLoad: true,
                       fields: ['category_name'],
                       proxy:{
                           type: 'jsonp',
                           url: 'http://192.168.0.8:8080/new/category_list.jsp',
                           reader:{
                               type: 'json',
                                rootProperty: 'root'
                           }
                       }
                   }   
               }
           }
           });
```

I am not able to display the category name in the list. Can anyone please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following and see if it helps.

1. Your JSP file is missing a : after the `root` node on the `String result` line. Change that line to

   ```
   String result = "{\"root:\"[{\"category_name\": \"Model number\"}]}";
   ```

   At the moment your JSP file does not deliver a correct JSON document and that's why you do not see results in the list.
2. Make sure that the JSP file delivers a correct JSON document. If the document does not start with `[`and ends with `]`you should add it to the beginning and the end of the line above.
3. Change the store proxy to:

   ```
   proxy:{
      type: 'ajax',
      url: 'http://192.168.0.8:8080/new/category_list.jsp',
      reader:{
          type: 'json',
          rootProperty: 'root'
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: [WARN][Anonymous] [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'Ext.dataview.List'; consider adding 'Ext.dataview.List' explicitly as a require of the corresponding class                         
Error:GET http://localhost:8080/Sample/192.168.0.8:8080/new/category_list.jsp?_dc=1334214266313&page=1&start=0&limit=25 404 (/Sample/192.168.0.8:8080/new/category_list.jsp)
sdk/src/data/Connection.js:301

Comment: Still no luck with getting it to work? Add `requires: ['Ext.dataview.List]` after `xtype:'bloglist',`.

Judging from the URL posted in the error message above you will have to check the URL. It uses `localhost:8080`and then tries to add the URL of your proxy which includes a full HTTP address. If you're loading JSON from your local machine you should remove the `http://192.168.0.8:8080`part from the proxy URL and make sure your store reads the correct URL.

Please be a bit more specific about what changes you did and what results you get.